# Flash Media Server doesn't play recorded video

Tags: activerecord, live-streaming, flash-media-server, playing

It is recording perfectly to the server with this method:

```
liveStream.publish("test", "record");
```

But when I want to play like so:

```
at NetStream.Record.Stop handler

var vd:Video = new Video(cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
vd.attachNetStream(liveStream);
liveStream.play("test");
addChild(vd);
```

Sometimes it is playing well, but usually it doesn't play and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my problem.

before i was adding metadata to my recorded video in "NetStream.Publish.Start" handler like so:

```
    case "NetStream.Publish.Start":
var metaData:Object = new Object(); 
metaData.title = "test"; 
metaData.width = cameraWidth; 
metaData.height = cameraHeight; 
liveStream.send("@setDataFrame" , "onMetaData", metaData);
    break;
```

And changed "NetStream.Record.Start" instead "NetStream.Publish.Start". Now it works fine for me.

I think if you want to playback any recorded stream, when your live stream triggers "Netstream.Record.Start", it is avaible to adding metadata.